# Json.NET serializeObject putting newline characters into data

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, json, json.net

I have a ASP.NET Web API REST service running on a server that feeds data back and forth to my Android Apps.  I use a lot of Newtonsoft Json with great success but it is causing me a problem on a new method I am writing.

In a nutshell I am reading a large String from my SQL Server DB, putting it into a simple object, serializing it out in a Json string, and posting an HTTP POST response. What is happening is that the serializeObject is inserting newline characters (/n) once every 76 characters into the string.

the following code...

```
    Logger.log("retPair.publicKey =  " + retPair.publicKey);
    returnString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(retPair);
    Logger.log("Verify Talker return is " + returnString);
```

Produces the following two log entries . . .

> 10/18/2015 3:19:36 PMDBAWP7  retPair.publicKey = 
>   MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAzQn5Lw2PTlVkSOjg7ycZMVDUmaGYQhVe
>   I82XcheaPDyr16tCp4P2oJCjKlKPeN1v5qN4kR4BKo3xjUwM+BWO6i3mr10C9/mbXUoInVXVODRu
>   lkdIXFPthSkBMytl5jAjaf1Ep4F3Y64WVwYXd9ASYpfNN5FMvxUzYbdkV7QNObsfHkAnr98uamFg
>   SJ0dGJ8svQ1DKiKz4db+zkzalXNHqh7mbV7kxRkT08GlocFEOp/xaLISlrH03CcKozerTbY/NkMx
>   XE7s7+wAuREgjKdNkpjRYUTMdm/QhxcvJf8UU7tE89POHkZ1wghPpAFIJ6kdCVBewrfaJVdcwJk8
>   WdzzaQIDAQAB
>
> 10/18/2015 3:19:36 PMDBAWP7  Verify Talker return is
>   {"phoneKey":"cathyblakely","publicKey":"MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAzQn5Lw2PTlVkSOjg7ycZMVDUmaGYQhVe\nI82XcheaPDyr16tCp4P2oJCjKlKPeN1v5qN4kR4BKo3xjUwM+BWO6i3mr10C9/mbXUoInVXVODRu\nlkdIXFPthSkBMytl5jAjaf1Ep4F3Y64WVwYXd9ASYpfNN5FMvxUzYbdkV7QNObsfHkAnr98uamFg\nSJ0dGJ8svQ1DKiKz4db+zkzalXNHqh7mbV7kxRkT08GlocFEOp/xaLISlrH03CcKozerTbY/NkMx\nXE7s7+wAuREgjKdNkpjRYUTMdm/QhxcvJf8UU7tE89POHkZ1wghPpAFIJ6kdCVBewrfaJVdcwJk8\nWdzzaQIDAQAB\n"}

BTW, the data is a Public encryption key.

As you can see the second log entry has /n every 76 characters.  Researching this problem on the web I see other people have gotten this problem but no one has received a response that eliminated the problem.  Formatting.NONE has not effect.

The product version of my Newtonsoft.Json.dll is 4.5.6.14930.  Anyone know why this might be happenning.  I know I can eliminate the \n in the string but that is my last resort.
Thanks,
Dean

Comment: Just to confirm, `retPair.publicKey` is a `string` and not a `byte[]`, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As seen in the JSON spec on [www.json.org](http://json.org), newlines in a string are encoded as `\n` when in JSON.

[image: Railroad Diagram for JSON String]

JSON.Net is not introducing newline characters into the output arbitrarily, but rather your original string *already* has newline characters, so they have to be encoded.

Comment: as you can see, there are no newline characters in retPair.publicKey so my original string does not already have newline characters.  They are clearly being put there by the serializeObject operation.  no?

Comment: It's difficult to *clearly* see, but all the `\n` characters align *exactly* with the newlines in the public key you pasted into your question.  Either it was there to begin with, or it's a copy/paste artifact and just coincidentally aligns.

Comment: Try `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(retPair.Replace("\n",""))` and see if you get different results.  Then you'll know for sure.

Comment: @MattJohnson I think you meant `retPair.publicKey.Replace("\n","")`.

Comment: @DeanBlakely I agree with Matt.  Most likely something in your code is calling [`Convert.ToBase64(publicKeyBytes, Base64FormattingOptions.InsertLineBreaks);`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8f9a8s97(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @MattJohnson sure enough I have unprintable newline characters in the original string in the data base and Json is dutifully encoding them as /n.  Now to find how they got there in the first place.  Thanks!